# league/flysystem-cached-adapter - does not work with laravel 9, what should I do?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-upgrade

I find a package in my Laravel project that stops me from upgrading to Laravel-9

> league/flysystem-cached-adapter

In the Laravel 8 documentaiont it says [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#driver-prerequisites)

> In addition, you may choose to install a cached adapter for increased performance:
> CachedAdapter: composer require league/flysystem-cached-adapter "~1.0"

So it kind of giving an idea that this package is `optional`

Laravel 9 Upgrade Guide does not mention this package at all [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade). Nothing about removing or leaving this package.

Should I delete it, or should I replace it with something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#flysystem-3

> ##### Cached Adapters
>
> Flysystem no longer supports "cached adapters". Thus, they have been removed from Laravel and any relevant configuration (such as the cache key within disk configurations) can be removed.